# jQuery ajax call “Not Found” error node js express

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

In my node js express app, I'm trying get data from database to a ejs file via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        datatype: "json",
        url: 'accelData',
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    }
```

I have created a route as well.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "root",
        database: "db_name"
    });

    con.connect(function(err){
        if(err) return;
    });

    con.query('SELECT * FROM table_name',function(err, result){
        if(err) return err;
        var response = {
            data : result
        };
        res.send(response);
    });
    con.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

and I added the route to `app.js` file.

```
var accelData = require('./routes/accelData');
app.use('/accelData', accelData);
```

When I run the node server, ajax request fails with `404` Not Found `http://localhost/accelData`

But when I try the url in my browser it shows me the data. 
What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending a POST request to a GET route.

That won't work.